Is it possible to receive parameters in app intent constructor before execute the 'perform' method?
I'm trying to receive a parameter in my app intent struct constructor to perform an action using this parameter value, but the perform method executes before my own init being executed. By the way, the WidgetConfigurationIntent protocol forces me to have an empty init, even I already have my own constructor, so I need to have two constructors, and the first one that is executed is the empty constructor and then the perform method. So, my 'custom' constructor is executed only after these two. That way, I always receiving nil when I going to use the value of myParameter in my perform intent method.
Does someone have any idea how to solve it?
My intent is somethig like this:
struct ConfigurationAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Configuration"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is an example widget.")
    
    var myParameter: MyCustomClass?
    
    init(myParameter: MyCustomClass?) {
        self.myParameter = myParameter
    }
    
    init() {}
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("intent was executed")
        
        return .result()
    }
}


Are you asking for a default value as a parameter?

@MdAbulKashem in my constructor, i'am not. i just accepting nil or a class, without define any default value to my constructor parameter

Why aren’t you creating (if necessary) the parameter inside the perform() func?

@mcritz can i do it? could you show me an example, please?

To handle actions, you can't use the WidgetConfigurationIntent, because this Intent type is to make configurations in your widget.
To execute actions, your class need to extend from AppIntent.
struct ExampleAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Example"
    
    @Parameter(title: "parameter") var parameter: String?
    
    init(parameter: String?) {
        self.parameter = parameter
    }
    
    init() {}
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("my parameter: \(parameter)")
        
        return .result()
    }
}

// In another file you can call it by the init
Button(intent: ExampleAppIntent(parameter: "My value")) {
    Text("Execute")
}

Font:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/widgetconfigurationintent
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/parameter-resolution


The expected means to handle parameters in an AppIntent is to use the @Parameter property wrapper.
ADC Documentation:

Overview “Providing your app’s capabilities to system services”
“Parameter Resolution”
Specific doc for “WidgetConfigurationIntent”

Example:
struct LionsTigersBearsAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Configuration"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is an example widget.")
    
    @Parameter(title: "Animal") var animal: AnimalClass
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("\(animal.name)! Oh my!")
        
        return .result()
    }
}


It seems like you're encountering a common issue with intents and their initialization flow in Swift. When you conform to the WidgetConfigurationIntent protocol, you're required to have an empty initializer due to protocol requirements. This is why your custom initializer isn't being called first.
One way to solve this is by setting your parameter after the empty initialiser has been called. You can do this by creating a separate method to set your parameter value, which you can call after the intent object has been initialised. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
struct ConfigurationAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Configuration"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is an example widget.")
    
    var myParameter: MyCustomClass?
    
    init() {}
    
    mutating func setParameter(_ parameter: MyCustomClass) {
        self.myParameter = parameter
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        guard let myParameter = myParameter else {
            // Handle the case where myParameter is nil
            return .failure(/* Provide an appropriate error */)
        }
        
        print("Intent was executed with myParameter: \(myParameter)")
        
        // Perform your action using myParameter
        
        return .success(/* Provide the result if any */)
    }
}

Then, after initialising an instance of ConfigurationAppIntent, you can call setParameter() to set the value of myParameter.
var intent = ConfigurationAppIntent()
intent.setParameter(/* Provide your custom parameter here */)

This way, you ensure that myParameter is set before calling the perform() method.

I couldn't use this solution in my case yet, but i still trying. Is there some reason to WidgetConfigurationIntent forces us to have an empty initializer? this protocol requirement makes no sense to me

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
